# Divi Theme HTML code is different in View Page Source than in the Firefox Inspector

Tags: css, html

I looked at code from a Divi Theme child theme in both Firefox View Page Source and Firefox Inspector. I was quite surprised to find that there are differences, specifically in the  and . Why would this happen?

Code in View Source

```
<header id="main-header" data-height-onload="89">
<div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
<div class="logo_container">
<span class="logo_helper"></span>
<a href="http://website.com/">
    <img src="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Final2017-e1506831049371.jpg" alt="Company" id="logo" data-height-percentage="64" />
</a>
</div>
<div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="89" data-fixed-height="40">
```

Code in Firebox Inspector

```
<header id="main-header" data-height-onload="104" data-height-loaded="true" data-fixed-height-onload="54" style="top: 32px;">
<div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
<div class="logo_container">
<span class="logo_helper"></span>
<a href="http://website.com/">
    <img src="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Final2017-e1506831049371.jpg" alt="Company" id="logo" data-height-percentage="64" data-actual-width="221" data-actual-height="115">
</a>
</div>
<div id="et-top-navigation" data-height="89" data-fixed-height="40" style="padding-left: 250px;">
```

Comment: You didn't include the links. Please also reword your question as its hard to understand clearly. Without looking though, are you talking about dynamic content loaded when the code is run compared to hard code in the source file? Divi uses shortcodes doesn't it?

Comment: This is a project where the site owner is very sensitive. I cannot link to the site. I tried adding the code, but for some reason, I'm having a problem with the system of the 4 spaces. The question isn't about the code so much as why View Page Source and Firefox Inspector would show different properties in a tag.

Comment: this difference could append because the source is the result sended by the server and in the inspector you see the DOM display which is the source eventualy modified by some JavaScript code

Comment: That makes sense. Could you set it as an answer so I can set it as the accepted answer?